# Prove that $7^{100} - 3^{100}$ is divisible by $1000$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences, binomial-theorem

> Prove that $7^{100} - 3^{100}$ is divisible by $1000$

Equivalently, we want to show that $$7^{100} = 3^{100} \pmod {1000}$$

I used WolframAlpha (not sure if that's the right way though) and found that $\varphi (250) = 100$.

So by Euler's theorem: $$7^{100} \equiv 7^{\varphi(250)} \equiv 1 \pmod {250} \\ 3^{100} \equiv 3^{\varphi(250)} \equiv 1 \pmod {250}$$

but of course, we want $\pmod {1000}$.

Is that what I'm intended to do in this exercise (how to proceed if so)? Is there a solution without the need to use WolframAlpha?

Thanks!

Comment: Use the formula $\varphi(p_1^{n_1}\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k})=p_1^{n_1-1}(p_1-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot p_k^{n_k-1}(p_k-1) $ where $p_1, \ldots,p_k $ are all mutually different prime numbers. In our case, $\varphi (2\cdot 5^3)=2^0 (2-1)\cdot 5^2 (5-1)=25\cdot 4=100$. No need to engage a computer.

Comment: @user8734617, but you knew a-priori that $\varphi(250) = 100$. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: My comment was not about how to solve the problem, see Lord Shark's answer, for example. It was more about how to, having undeniably used 'Wolfie A', justify your solution by other means. Sorry for any misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wolfie A is **never** the right way.

By the Chinese remainder theorem, all you need is to prove both
$$7^{100}\equiv3^{100}\pmod8$$ and
$$7^{100}\equiv3^{100}\pmod{125}.$$
You have already done the latter. But $7^2\equiv1\pmod 8$
and $3^2\equiv1\pmod 8$ so it's a fair bet that $7^{100}\equiv3^{100}
\pmod8$ too.

Comment: Oooh, I don't know about that! There are problems in mathematics for which computer assistance is entirely appropriate, aren't there? Isn't that precisely why we invented computers? In this case, your solution is great, and I agree that the machines needn't get involved.....

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Yes, but computer assistance is available without Wolfie.

Comment: For everyone? All the time? I'm puzzled by your combination of contempt and pet names.....

Comment: I have showed the latter using a computer. So, following your methodology: it is sufficient to show that $3^{100} = 7^{100} \pmod 5$ (since $5 \mid 125$) and we can see that $3^2 \equiv 7^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.

Comment: Thank you @LordSharktheUnknown!

Comment: @Elimination: $1\equiv 41 \pmod 5$ and $1\equiv 41 \pmod 8$, but clearly $1\not\equiv 41 \pmod{1000}$. Note that $125 = 5\cdot 25$, but $\gcd(5,25)\ne 1$.

Comment: Come on guys, if computer assistance in this sort of problems was allowed, what's to stop the OP to just calculate the three last digits of $7^{100}$ and $3^{100}$ etc.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs If computer assistance was allowed, this kind of problem would be redundant. In that case, OP could just calculate the number and divide it by 1000. Problems like this are posed as an exercise, and not because their solution is of particular interest.

Comment: @celtschk, oh I see (so I used CRT wrongly) - how can I show the latter equivalence then? ($3^{100} \equiv 7^{100} \pmod {125}$)

Comment: @JannikPitt, I have not suggested for a moment that computer assistance is appropriate on *this* question. I only took issue with the claim that WA is "never" the right way to do anything. Please don't read more into my comments than that. I value number theory exercises very much, thank you!

Comment: @user8734617, I was never talking about what is "allowed", nor about "this kind of problem". I was only addressing a categorical claim made by Lord Shark, and I think he understood that.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Far enough, Lord Shark did sound categorical, didn't he? I would still say that he was right, in the first approximation. (Students need categorical rules to tell right from wrong, once they grow up the rules are relaxed.)

Comment: @GTonyJacobs Oh okay,  sorry I misunderstood you! In that case, of course you're right.

Comment: @Elimination: I'd see that $3^5 = 243 = 250-7 \equiv -243\pmod{125}$ (that's easily calculated even without a computer). Thus $3^{100} =(3^5)^{20}\equiv(-7)^{20}\pmod{125}$. But with an even exponent, the minus sign cancels, so you only have to check $7^{20}\equiv7^{100} \pmod{125}$. Since $\gcd(7^{20},125)=0$, you can cancel out $7^{20}$ remaining with the $7^{80}\equiv 1 \pmod{125}$. Next, I'd try small divisors of $80$. $7^2=49$ obviously doesn't work. $7^4 = (50-1)^2 = 2401$ isn't good either, but $01$ at the end looks good, however we'd need to get rid of the $4$ in the hundred's place. …

Comment: That's best done by trying to do another $()^5$ so we get a $()^{20}$ in total; note that we can drop the initial $2$ for that as $1000\equiv 0\pmod{125}$, and we only need the lowest two terms of the binomial formula as $100^2\equiv 0\pmod{125}$, so $7^{20}=(7^4)^5\equiv 401^5 \equiv 5\cdot 400 + 1 = 2001\equiv 1\pmod{125}$. Thus $7^{80}=(7^{20})^4\equiv 1^4=1\pmod{125}$ which we've seen above is equivalent to $3^{100}\equiv 7^{100} \pmod{125}$. But then, the binomial formula ansatz from other answers is IMHO the better solution in this case anyway (note I also used a binomial formula above).

Comment: By the way, could you please explain what CRT has to do with that? Obviously, the system is of the form requested for CRT (i.e. $(8, 125)=1$) but why it it needed here? What does CRT supply here?

Answer (score 5):

\begin{eqnarray} 
7^{100}-3^{100} &=& (10-3)^{100}-3^{100}\\
 &=& \underbrace{{100\choose 0}10^{100}-{100\choose 1}10^{99}\cdot 3+...-{100\choose 97}10^3 \cdot 3^{97}}_{10^3k}+{100\choose 98}10^2 \cdot 3^{98} -{100\choose 99}10 \cdot 3^{99}+3^{100}-3^{100}\\
&=&1000k +50\cdot 99\cdot10^2 \cdot 3^{98} -100\cdot 10 \cdot 3^{99}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: You've got some of the last exponents wrong. For example, $2+99 = 101 \ne 100$.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

By the binomial theorem,
$$
3^{100}
=(7-10)^{100}
=7^{100}-\binom{100}{1}7^{99}10+\binom{100}{2}7^{98}10^2 + 10^3a
$$
Now
$
\binom{100}{1}10=1000
$
and
$
\binom{100}{2}10^2 = 495000
$

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the following method, which is rather unusual. If it doesn't work please comment why. Also, since this is probably too long to be a comment, I have posted it here.

Firstly, we can factor the expression by the difference of two squares: $$7^{100}-3^{100}=(7^{50}-3^{50})(7^{50}+3^{50})=(7^{25}-3^{25})(7^{25}+3^{25})(7^{50}-3^{50})$$
We shall concentrate on only the first two factors and use the facts that $7^5=16807$ ends in $07$ and that $3^5=243$ ends in $43$. Note that $43^5 = 147008443$.

Now $7^{25}=(7^5)^5$, so by the first fact $7^5$ ends in $...807$. Similarly, $3^{25}=(3^5)^5$, so by the second fact, $3^{25}$ ends in $...443$.

Hence $7^{25}-3^{25}$ ends in $64$ (since $807-443=364$) and $7^{25}+3^{25}$ ends in $250$ (since $807+443=1250$). The result follows since $1000$ divides $64 \times 250$.

Comment: 14 ends with 4 but 14×250 ends in 500.

Comment: @user8734617 edited: $64 \times 250 = 16000$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$7^2=50-1,7^4=(50-1)^2=1+100\cdot24$

Using binomial expansion,

$7^{4n}=(1+100\cdot24)^n\equiv1+2400n\pmod{1000}\equiv1+400n$

$3^4=1+80$

$3^{4m}=(1+80)^m\equiv1+80m+80^2\binom m2\pmod{1000}$

Answer (score 2):

$$(5+2)^{100}-(5-2)^{100} = \sum_{\substack{0\leq k \leq 100\\ k\text{ odd}}}\binom{100}{k} 5^k 2^{101-k}$$
hence the LHS $\pmod{5^3}$ is just $\binom{100}{1}5^1 2^{100}$, i.e. zero. The LHS is also a multiple of $8$ since any odd square is $\equiv 1\pmod{8}$. By the Chinese remainder theorem $7^{100}-3^{100}\equiv 0\pmod{1000}$.

Answer (score 1):

Using http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelFunction.html,

$\lambda(1000)=\cdots=100$

$\implies a^{100}\equiv1\pmod{1000}$ for $(a,1000)=1\iff(a,10)=1$